Unable to install Automatic1111 Stable Diffusion on 24.04 due to Python 3.12.3
I'm contemplating going back to Ubuntu 22.04 because I'm facing an issue with installing Stable Diffusion (via Automatic1111) on my newly installed Ubuntu 24.04. The sole purpose of installing Ubuntu on this gaming laptop (with a discrete 3070 gpu) is to run stable diffusion.
Based on my limited finding, it seems Ubuntu 24.04 comes pre-packaged with Python 3.12.3. But the webgui from Automatic1111 only runs on 3.10x. (I don't have the source right now, but it was on one of the many threads I've been reading since last night).
I thought I could try installing an earlier version of Python, but I'm not well-versed in this, and I felt like this could break things.
I understand 24.04 is brand new at this point, so there's not a lot of info out there about this. I'm posting here with the hope that more folks will land on this if they face the issue, and we will all get a solution. :)
Thank you!

You can use anaconda to set up a python3.10 virtual environment. Don't try to replace the default python version. You will end up breaking Ubuntu.

Thank you! I'm going to go ahead and install 22.04, as I'm running into a bunch of other bugs here and there.

I'm running Kubuntu 24.04 (which is just Ubuntu pre-configured to work with KDE by default). I was able to get Automatic1111 (and also Stable Diffusion Forge) working with a few adjustments.

Add the PPA for extra Python libraries to the Ubuntu package manager. For more detailed instructions see here: https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.
The commands are basically this:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
   sudo apt update


Install a Stable Diffusion compatible python version AND the python venv module package.

   sudo apt install python3.10 python3.10-venv


(For this next step, I recreated the whole 'venv' folder, just to be sure of avoiding conflicts. This may not be strictly necessary.)
In the folder where you installed / extracted / downloaded your Stable Diffusion program (Automatic1111 or Forge), rename any existing 'venv' folder to something else. I suggest 'venv.old'.

Create a new 'venv' folder with this command:


    python3.10 -m venv "venv"


In the folder where you installed / extracted / downloaded your Stable Diffusion program (Automatic1111 or Forge), edit the file 'webui-user.sh'.
Change the section:

    # python3 executable
    #python_cmd="python3"

to be:

    # python3 executable
    python_cmd="python3.10"


Optional: Make any other custom changes you want to the 'webui-user.sh' file, such has the COMMANDLINE_ARGS parameters.
Now start the webui for Stable Diffusion as normal. If you followed the steps to create a fresh 'venv' folder, this will trigger a full reinstall and download any necessary packages, and compile them.

That should fix your Stable Diffusion for Ubuntu 24.04!
Note: Stable Diffusion Forge works more or less better than Automatic1111 (slightly faster also), and supports Python 3.11. So you can adjust the version numbers for that and do the same configuration steps.

Hi, thank you! For now, I switched back to 22.04, but when I inevitably upgrade to 24.04, I'll follow these instructions. I appreciate your help! :)

The official instructions currently advise an answer similar to C.D.'s.  However, I prefer not to install system-wide packages when not necessary, much less full PPAs.  So with that in mind, using Archisman Panigrahi's tip, here is how to do it via Anaconda.  All steps below can be done in user mode (no root/system changes required):

Download Miniconda: wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

Install Miniconda: bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

If you didn't have it modify your shell then do:
eval "$(/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.YOUR_SHELL_NAME hook)"

Go into your stable diffusion folder: cd stable-diffusion-webui

If you already had a venv, move it out of the way mv venv venv-old

Stable diffusion wants python 3.10, so create a venv conda create --name venv python=3.10

Enter the venv: conda activate venv

Start webui: ./webui.sh


That worked for me, and also solved my error "RuntimeError: Torch is not able to use GPU" from when I upgraded Ubuntu 23.10 => Ubuntu 24.04.
Now that it's set up and working, I made a simple shell script to enter the venv and run webui:
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(/home/aiart/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
cd ~/stable-diffusion-webui
# conda create --name venv python=3.10  ## Only needed for initial setup
conda activate venv
./webui.sh


A bit late to respond here, but thank you!
